# Como pegar o resultado da janela que pede para ativar o Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Dentro de uma aplicação android, tenho uma tela que necessita que o bluetooth esteja ativado, caso ele esteja desabilitado, a parte do código abaixo solicita ao usuário que habilite o mesmo:

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
       (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            ((MainActivity) context).startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }
```

Até ai beleza, quando o bluetooth está desabilitado, aparece a tela nativa do Android pedindo para habilita-lo

"O aplicativo está solicitando permissão para ativar o Bluetooth. Permitir?"

Caso o usuário aperte "SIM" ele habilita o bluetooth, porém, não achei como tratar caso o usuário aperte "NAO".

Answer (score 1):

Achei a resposta da minha pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês.

Basta aplicar a função *onActivityResult* na activity em questão (no meu caso *MainActivity*)

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // Answer of bluetooth intent
    if (resultCode == 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```